# How do i fork my development repo into a new branch of my production repo using Github

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have two repo's which I'd like to keep separate. One for development, branches are features/fixes etc, the other is a production release, where its branches are for versions.

I'm still very new to version control, so I'm not even sure I'm doing it correctly.

What I'd like to do, is fork master from development, then that fork be a new branch in production with a version number, say 1.3 etc.

Is this possible, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way is to use one repo with branches for features and either branches or tags for versions. That makes it much easier to merge branches and move commits around, compared to having two repos. It also saves confusion on the part of the developers.

Comment: Agreed. Having two repositories will make life far more difficult.  Read this article:  [A successful branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).  While that's likely more complex than you need, it will give you ideas on how branches can be used to support a production workflow.

Comment: Thankyou very much. This will make it easier.